# Python Traceback (Most recent call last)

Tags: python

When I try to import models using Rip addon I see an error saying traceback error but my PYTHON traceback error

`AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'`

[image: Blender screenshot with a traceback that ends "AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'".]

Answer (score 4):

The `time.clock()` function is deprecated and was removed in Python 3.8. Blender 2.93 ships with Python 3.9, so any code that uses `time.clock()` won't work in 2.93.

[Here](https://github.com/xpawelsky/RipImport/issues/5) is a bug report for this issue on the RipImport repo.

You can fix this by either

1. Using Blender 2.92, or
2. Using [Fighterbuilder's fork](https://github.com/Fighterbuilder/RipImport) of the RipImport addon, which fixes this bug.